# Conditional required on formControl

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I fellows,

I need the following relationship between 2 formControls. When one has value the other is not required. When one has no value, therefore the otherone is required. I mean only one of them is required.

The relationship is between sites and salesAreas. This template validation doesnt work:

```
required="!userForm.controls.saleAreas.value.length
```

This one using #saleAreas doesnt work either:

```
required="!saleAreas._value.length"
```

The required is placed inside a mat-select

I've also tried this, it doesn't work either:

```
<mat-select placeholder="{{ 'user.detail.sites' | translate }}" 
                    formControlName="sites" 
                    multiple 
                    #sites 
                    (ngModelChange)="checkSA(salesAreas)">

private setValidatorRequired(eventL) {
const validorArr = [];

if (!eventL) {
  validorArr.push(Validators.required);
 }

return Validators.compose(validorArr);
}

setSitesValidators(eventL) {
this.userForm.controls.sites.setValidators(this.setValidatorRequired(eventL));
this.userForm.controls.sites.updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf:true});
}
```

Angular version 12.2.16

Answer (score -1):

With [required] it works perfectly

Comment: A mat-select multiple return an array with the element selected or null if no element selected. it's important know it. the best way is writte in the .html `<pre>{{userForm?.value|json}}</pre>`. BTW not use (ngModelChanges) use the event [`(selectionChange)`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#directives)